# Not able to set default value in Material Multiselect Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, multi-select

I am trying to implement a multiselect in Angular using Material.

When the page is opened in Edit mode, some of the types should be selected as default in the Multiselect but it is not working in my case.

Below is the HTML:

```
 <mat-form-field >
      <mat-select  placeholder="DocTypes" [(value)]="selectedDocType" formControlName="docTypes" multiple>
        <mat-option  *ngFor="let doc of docs" [value]="doc.name">{{doc.name}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

And I am filling SelectedDocType as below:

```
  selectedDocType: string[] = new Array();
 resp.forEach(x => {
                    this.selectedDocType.push(x.name);
                  });
```

Here resp contains correct doc type. For example CV.

Weired thing is when I set the selectedDocType as below then it works:

```
this.selectedDocType = ["CV"];
```

But it does not work when I push under the for each as I mentioned above. Both of them is having 1 value in the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Update: Doc format is as below:

```
export interface DocTypes{
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you try this `this.selectedDocType =  resp.map(x=>x,name)` , if this dosent work, can you provide a plunker/codesandbox with demo of the issue.

Comment: If I understand this correctly you want the options to be a list of x.name? Or is there a different problem?

Comment: I tried that but still same problem. I cant create a plunker because the data is coming from backend. Let me try though @ХристиянХристов

Comment: No @Mannaroth - x.name is coming correctly and data is also binding correctly. options are not getting selected by default in Edit page. It works if I assign hard coded data.

Comment: What is the doc format  ?

Comment: It is simple id, name @Sescudero. I have updated the question

Comment: Ok so res has the values which should be selected?

Comment: Yes right @Mannaroth. When I give hard coded string then it works but same data is coming from resp, it does not work,

Comment: are docs and resp objects or arrays? They seem to be objects, but is it necessary?

Comment: I don't have a form, but does this work? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsdudq    check app.component.ts for logic and app.component.html for HTML let me know so I can answer it, I am just confused if the form is a significant factor and if you need resp and docs to be objects or arrays

Comment: Thanks you all for the help. In my case the issue was quite different. I have added the answer for that.

Comment: Thanks for writing it down @Mannaroth. I had to assign the value to a local variable first and then it worked. I have added the answer for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me.

The issue was with the assignment of the response as I was assigning the response directly to the variable.

Instead of that, I had to first assign the value to a local variable and then I assign the value to the selectedDocType and it worked:

```
name: [];
 for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                name[i] = resp[i].id;
              }
this.selectedDocType = name;
```

This way selectedDocType was assigned with the correct values required.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is a known issue with material select.
It selects by object **reference** and not by value.

- which is why it works with just strings but fails with actual objects...

You can quite easily override that behavior using a built-in input [compareWith](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)

Here's a little [stackblitz demo for you to get the concept](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdo6m6?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts):

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select multiple [(ngModel)]="selectedObjects" [compareWith]="comparer">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let iobject of allObjects" [value]="iobject">{{iobject.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Component:**

```
interface obj {
  name: string,
  value: number
}

@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example'
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {

  selectedObjects : obj[];

  allObjects : obj[] = [
    {name: 'AAA', value: 1},
    {name: 'BBB', value: 2},
    {name: 'CCC', value: 3}
  ];
  
  ngOnInit() {
    // define default selection
    this.selectedObjects = [{name: 'AAA', value: 99}, {name: 'CCC', value: 99}];    
  }

  comparer(o1: obj, o2: obj): boolean {
    // if possible compare by object's name property - and not by reference.
    return o1 && o2 ? o1.name === o2.name : o1 === o2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But in my case the issue was different. I have added the answer for that.